# mysql substring / get id from string

Tags: mysql, regex

I have IDs in the following syntax in a MySQL DB:

```
1_5f902d_QCwOZLEJEvHB
c6475d_1_9BAZWQeTeP1W
2_0841fe_VtfJl1DkBnPZ
1bfd49_4_dKbKktFRHP0U
```

I want to extract the main id (6 digits). From the examples this is:

```
 5f902d
 c6475d
 0841fe
 1bfd49
```

For the first and the third example I use within a case query:

```
(case
            WHEN length(ID) = 21 THEN RIGHT(Left(ID,8),6)
            ELSE ID     
    END
    ) as id_
```

but for the second and the fourth it doesn't work with length. I think I have to use regex, but I don't know how to work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for the cases you have specified:

```
select (case when substring(id, 2, 1) = '_'
             then substring(id, 3, 6)
             else left(id, 6)
        end)
```

Normally I would use `like` for the `when` condition, but `_` is an escape character and `substring()` is just as easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp to test where the underscore is, and then extract the appropraite substring.

```
CASE WHEN id REGEXP '^[0-9]_.{19}$' THEN SUBSTRING(id, 3, 6)
     WHEN id REGEXP '^.{6}_.{14}$' THEN LEFT(id, 6)
END AS id_
```

Ending the regexp with `.{19}$` and `.{14}$` also implements the `LENGTH(id) = 21` check at the same time.

Comment: Great, that works fine within my case! Thanks a lot. The length check within regex is also really nice.